# Creating a method that closes an account

Tags: java, oop, object

This is the instance variable from the UML diagram:
`public boolean closeAccount()` where returns true if account is successfully closed and false, otherwise.

Account is identified by an account number and account cannot be closed if balance is negative.

So far I have:

```
public boolean closeAccount() {
if (number != null && balance >=0 ) {
            //Unsure what to put here
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

The account even when closed should still exist for searching and display purposes. Any idea what to code to add which would qualify as "closing" the account?

Comment: This really depends on the whole example. The simplest thing would be to just mark it as closed (with a boolean flag).

Comment: Agreeing with @Henry - does an `Account` have a boolean attribute `isOpen`? Or is it up to you to design that portion?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code which should put there depends on your business logic and project structure.
For example,
Add a method void close(){or any name one :3} to your Account class. This method should close the current account by appending “CLOSED” to the account name and setting the balance to 0. (The account number should remain unchanged.) Also, decrement the total number of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to handle states in your Account entity class:

```
public class Account {

    private String number; //following this format: 00223993002
    private long balance;
    .
    .
    .
    private Status status = Status.OPEN; //by default, account is open
  
}
```

And having (for example):

```
enum Status {OPEN, CLOSING, CLOSED}
```

Now, avoid to put business logic in your entity classes, it should be in a `service` class:

```
public class AccountService {

   public boolean closeAccount(String accountNumber) {

      Account target = this.getAccountByNumber(accountNumber);
      if (target != null && target.getBalance() >= 0 ) {
         target.setStatus(Status.CLOSING);
         return this.saveOrUpdateAccount(target);
      }
      return false;
   }

   public Account getAccountByNumber(String accountNumber) {...}

   public boolean saveOrUpdateAccount(Account account) {...}
    
}
```